# Custom react hook triggers api call multiple times

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I cannot figure out how to handle my function components calling my api repeatedly.  I have two components which retrieve data, one of them calls the api twice.  Once before the second component once after.

I am using a custom react hook and axios get method to retrieve the data.  My two components are are nested.  The first component when loads and fetches data.  Inside this component is a child component which when renders it fetches data right before passing the first set of data as props to another child component.  When it completes loading it reloads the first child component which again calls the api for data.  I understand the function components reload on state change.  I would be happy for it to not call the api a second time.  Is there a way to check if it already has data and bypass the api call?

Custom hook to retrieve data

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const dataFetchReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_INIT":
      return { ...state, isLoading: true, hasErrored: false };
    case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        hasErrored: false,
        errorMessage: "",
        data: action.payload
      };
    case "FETCH_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        hasErrored: true,
        errorMessage: "Data Retrieve Failure"
      };
    case "REPLACE_DATA":
      // The record passed (state.data) must have the attribute "id"
      const newData = state.data.map(rec => {
        return rec.id === action.replacerecord.id ? action.replacerecord : rec;
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        hasErrored: false,
        errorMessage: "",
        data: newData
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

const useAxiosFetch = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
  const [url] = useState(initialUrl);

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, {
    isLoading: false,
    hasErrored: false,
    errorMessage: "",
    data: initialData
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_INIT" });

      try {
        let result = await axios.get(url);
        if (!didCancel) {
          dispatch({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", payload: result.data });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        if (!didCancel) {
          dispatch({ type: "FETCH_FAILURE" });
        }
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      didCancel = true;
    };
  }, [url]);

  const updateDataRecord = record => {
    dispatch({
      type: "REPLACE_DATA",
      replacerecord: record
    });
  };

  return { ...state, updateDataRecord };
};

export default useAxiosFetch;
```

Main component which renders the "CompaniesDropdown" twice inside

CompaniesDropdown is one of three dropdowns within the ListFilterContainer component but the only one which calls the api more than once. The other two dropdowns load by selection of the CompaniesDropdown.

```
import React, { useMemo, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import InvoiceList from "../src/Components/Lists/InvoiceList";
import useAxiosFetch from "../src/useAxiosFetch";
import { ConfigContext } from "./_app";
import ListFilterContainer from "../src/Components/Filters/InvoiceFilters";
// import "../css/ListView.css";

const Invoices = props => {
  const context = useContext(ConfigContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Captive Billing :: Invoices";
  });

  const {
    data,
    isLoading,
    hasErrored,
    errorMessage,
    updateDataRecord
  } = useAxiosFetch("https://localhost:44394/Invoice/GetInvoices/false", []);

  const newInvoicesList = useMemo(
    () => data
    //     .filter(
    //       ({ sat, sun }) => (speakingSaturday && sat) || (speakingSunday && sun)
    //     )
    //     .sort(function(a, b) {
    //       if (a.firstName < b.firstName) {
    //         return -1;
    //       }
    //       if (a.firstName > b.firstName) {
    //         return 1;
    //       }
    //       return 0;
    //     }),
    // [speakingSaturday, speakingSunday, data]
  );

  const invoices = isLoading ? [] : newInvoicesList;

  if (hasErrored)
    return (
      <div>
        {errorMessage}&nbsp;"Make sure you have launched "npm run json-server"
      </div>
    );

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  const dataProps = {
    data: invoices,
    titlefield: "invoiceNumber",
    titleHeader: "Invoice Number:",
    childPathRoot: "invoiceDetail",
    childIdField: "invoiceId",
    childDataCollection: "invoiceData"
  };

  var divStyle = {
    height: context.windowHeight - 100 + "px"
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <ListFilterContainer />
      <section style={divStyle} id="invoices" className="card-container">
        <InvoiceList data={dataProps} />
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

Invoices.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const isServer = !!req;
  return { isServer };
};

export default Invoices;
```

Actual result is described above.  My main concern is to not have the api calls more than once.

Here is some additional code to help.  It is the filter control mentioned above. It, as you will notice really just contains dropdowns and a text box.  The first dropdown is the one that calls the api twice.  The second two are not visible until that one is selected.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import CompaniesDropdown from "../Dropdowns/CompaniesDropdown";
import LocationsDropdown from "../Dropdowns/LocationsDropdown";
import AccountsDropdown from "../Dropdowns/AccountsDropdown";
import Search from "./SearchFilter/SearchFilter";

const InvoiceFilters = props => {
  const [company, setCompany] = useState("");
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(undefined);
  const [account, setAccount] = useState(undefined);

  const handleClientChange = clientValue => {
    setCompany(clientValue);
  };

  const handleLocationsChange = locationValue => {
    setLocation(locationValue);
  };

  const handleAccountsChange = AccountValue => {
    setAccount(AccountValue);
  };

  return (
    <section className="filter-container mb-3">
      <div className="form-row">
        <div className="col-auto">
          <CompaniesDropdown change={e => handleClientChange(e)} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-auto">
          <LocationsDropdown
            selectedCompany={company}
            change={e => handleLocationsChange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-auto">
          <AccountsDropdown
            selectedCompany={company}
            change={e => handleAccountsChange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-auto">
          <Search />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

InvoiceFilters.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const isServer = !!req;
  return { isServer };
};

export default InvoiceFilters;
```

Also the datalist

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import InvoiceListRecord from "./InvoiceListRecord";

const InvoiceList = props => {
  let dataCollection = props.data.data;

  return dataCollection.length == 0 ? "" : dataCollection.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <section key={"item-" + index} className="card text-left mb-3">
        <header className="card-header">
          <span className="pr-1">{props.data.titleHeader}</span>
          <Link
            href={
              "/" +
              props.data.childPathRoot +
              "?invoiceId=" +
              item[props.data.childIdField]
            }
            as={
              "/" +
              props.data.childPathRoot +
              "/" +
              item[props.data.childIdField]
            }
          >
            <a>{item[props.data.titlefield]}</a>
          </Link>{" "}
        </header>
        <div className="card-body">
          <div className="row">
            <InvoiceListRecord
              data={item}
              childDataCollection={props.data.childDataCollection}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  });
};

InvoiceList.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  console.log("Get Intitial Props works: Invoices Page!");
  const isServer = !!req;
  return { isServer };
};

export default InvoiceList;
```

and the list items component.

```
import React from "react";

const InvoiceListRecord = props => {
  var invoiceData = JSON.parse(props.data[props.childDataCollection]);

  return invoiceData.map((invKey, index) => {
    return (
      <div className="col-3 mb-1" key={"item-data-" + index}>
        <strong>{invKey.MappedFieldName}</strong>
        <br />
        {invKey.Value}
      </div>
    );
  });
};

export default InvoiceListRecord;
```

Answer (score 0):

The API is not called more than once if the url is the same. It just gets the value from `data` variable. The api call is not made again, unless the `url` changes.

I created an example from your code, changing all the unknown components to div. I added a `console.log` in the `useEffect` of the `useAxiosFetch` hook. And to re-render the component, I added a button to increment the count.

You'll see that the console.log from the hook is printed only once, even though the component re-renders on every button click. The value just comes from the `data` variable from the hook and the api call is not made again and again.

[image: Edit loving-cartwright-03y8h]

Comment: Maybe I should supply you some more components for you to test better.  I can assure you that it is calling the api twice as I put a breakpoint in the api and it hits the method twice.

Comment: Also, you are correct.  The url is not changing.  Here they are.
https://localhost:44394/Utilities/GetCompanies
useAxiosFetch.js:55 https://localhost:44394/Invoice/GetInvoices/false
FetchDropdownData.js:55 https://localhost:44394/Utilities/GetCompanies

Comment: It is hard to understand your code with all the holes in it that I can't fill without knowing what you are doing. If you can add the whole code to codesandbox or send me a git repo, I can check it out.